# A curve C has an equation of $y = f(x)$, where $ f(x) = \frac{4x}{\sqrt{4+x}+\sqrt{4-x}} $, and $ -4\le x\le4. $

Tags: binomial-theorem

This question is Part $A$ of a binomial theorem question. I am unable to continue as I am stuck here. I really appreciate any help.

> A curve $C$ has an equation of $y = f(x)$, where
>
> $$ f(x) = \frac{4x}{\sqrt{4+x}+\sqrt{4-x}} $$
>
> and $$ -4\le x\le4. $$
>
> The question is:
>
> - Show that $$ f(x) = k(\sqrt{4+x}-\sqrt{4-x}) $$ for some constant $k$ to be determined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply by the conjugate.
$$f(x) = \dfrac{4x}{\sqrt{4+x}+\sqrt{4-x}}\cdot \dfrac{\sqrt{4+x}-\sqrt{4-x}}{\sqrt{4+x}-\sqrt{4-x}} = \text{?}$$

Comment: Thanks! So simple but i didnt thought of it.